# spread operator when flattening array gives - error TS2769

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to flatten an array and am getting an error -  - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.

I did this in stackblitz and it worked fine.

The spread operator is getting the error: ...this.selectedInstitutions

```
  selectedInstitutions = [
    [{ displayValue: 'ABC', id: 781 }],
    [{ displayValue: 'DEF', id: 782 }],
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedInstitutions = [].concat(...this.selectedInstitutions);
  }
```

The error message is:

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you provide more details on the error message? The *error TS2769: No overload matches this call.* message is too brief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `[].concat(someValue)`, the empty array `[]` doesn't have any type specified and is inferred to be of `never[]` type.

From [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#exhaustiveness-checking)

> The never type is assignable to every type; however, no type is assignable to never (except never itself).

So when [strictNullChecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) typescript option is enabled, you will get an error when trying to assign any other type to `never[]` which is exactly what happens when you do something as:

```ts
[].concat(...this.selectedInstitutions)
```

You can overcome the error by type casting as:

```ts
this.selectedInstitutions = ([] as any[]).concat(...this.selectedInstitutions);
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAzioMZhAEwJIDspgJZgK7YHsMIBeCAbQCgIaKBvCJLKAB2AEMBPANXeFxAAuCAHIAggCEAwiIA0ELEmEB2ABwBGCAF8AurOq1yDJqw48+A4SIAiAUQBichUohqATNr0GdAbkoB6f2hYEARkdEwcfCwiKFIKHQA6OCI4djAACkTsmHhEVAxsPEIMAEo-SlzQ-Iii6Nj4jPIdCHY49jROZtLk1PSsnJCwgsjimLK-FIwCUETgAgBzDKrh2qiSqHKgA)

**PS:** Use of `any` type is discouraged, so if you already have defined a type for `selectedInstitutions`, use the same while type casting.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to flatten. Your data is already flat, it's only 1 level deep (no inner nesting). Combining an array with data to a new array and assigning it back to itself doesn't do much, end result is always the same, what are you trying to accomplish?

Anyway, adding a type declaration should resolve the issue.

`([] as string[]).concat('foo')`

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedInstitutions = ([] as any[]).concat(...this.selectedInstitutions);
  }
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-scfukg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Actually, it isn't. it is an array of arrays and needs to be an array of objects. if I don't flatten it, I can't use it in angular multi-select dropdown. I also can't map it like the following because it says displayValue doesn't exist. If I flatten it, it works fine.

    const temp = this.selectedInstitutions.map(x => <any>{
      title: x.displayValue
    });